# I am trying to make a button where if you click it it turns purple, button was originally blue, but if clicked again then it turn back to blue

Tags: python, tkinter, button, events

I am trying to make a button where if you click it it turns purple, button was originally blue, what I made. But now I want button to change to blue if clicked twice or if double clicked. How to I keep track of clicks??

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def click_row_1_B():
    B_bingo_row_1.config(bg="#B900FF")
## if clicked twice :B_bingo_row_1.config(bg="#B900FF")

B_bingo_row_1 = Button(
    root, text="B1", bg="#00CCFF", font=("Helvetica", 20), command=click_row_1_B
)

B_bingo_row_1.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This handles counting multiple single clicks and doing something based on that - not using the double clicked handler for fast double clicks - see [ncica's answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70863327/7505395).*

Functions are just other objects, you can add properties to them:

- store a list of colors at the function
- store a number for clicks on the function
- increase the number when clicked
- handle color changes inside the function

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def click_row_1_B():
    """Provide a fancy multicolored button click handler that
    chages backgroundcolor based on clicks and an assigned color list"""
    # increase the click count
    click_row_1_B.click += 1

    # lengths of color list
    colorLen = len(click_row_1_B.colors)

    # set background to "click % colorLen" index in color list
    B_bingo_row_1.config(bg = click_row_1_B.colors[click_row_1_B.click % colorLen])

# put properties on the function - do it before you use them (avoid NameError)
# colors will be cycled in order with each click, wrapping around
click_row_1_B.click = 0    
click_row_1_B.colors = ["#00ccff", "#B900ff", "#eee993"]

B_bingo_row_1 = Button(
    root, text = "B1", bg = click_row_1_B.colors[0], # 1st col to start
    font = ("Helvetica", 20), command = click_row_1_B)

B_bingo_row_1.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

| start | after 1st click | after 2nd click | after 3rd click |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Start] | [image: after 1st click] | [image: after 2nd click] | [image: Start] |

Comment: this works way better thanks, for the visuals too!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can always bind  and  to one widget but with different functions

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def click_row_1_B(event):
    B_bingo_row_1.config(bg="#B900FF")
def double_click_row_1_B(event):
    B_bingo_row_1.config(bg="#00CCFF")

B_bingo_row_1 = Button(root, text="B1", bg="#00CCFF", font=("Helvetica", 20))
B_bingo_row_1.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky="nsew")

B_bingo_row_1.bind('<Double-Button-1>', double_click_row_1_B)
B_bingo_row_1.bind('<Button-1>', click_row_1_B)

root.mainloop()
```

For each widget, it's possible to bind Python functions and methods to an event.

> widget.bind(event, handler)

A mouse button is pressed with the mouse pointer over the widget. The detail part specifies which button, e.g. The left mouse button is defined by the event **Button-1**, the middle button by **Button-2**, and the rightmost mouse button by **Button-3**.

**Button-4** defines the scroll up event on mice with wheel support and and **Button-5** the scroll down.

Similar to the Button event, see above, but the button is double clicked instead of a single click. To specify the left, middle or right mouse button use **Double-Button-1**, **Double-Button-2**, and **Double-Button-3** respectively.